# How to remove questions with repeated items?

Tags: r-exams

Frequently, when generating questions based on parameters, some generated questions have to be eliminated because, within such a questions, it sometimes happens that some items are the same.

My code is the following.

The question:

````
```{r, include = FALSE}
a <- sample(1:1,1)
b <- sample(1:1,1)
```

Question
========

Let $z = `r (a^2)*(b^2)`$. Hence, $\sqrt{z}$ is equal to:

Answerlist
----------

* $`r a*b`$
* $`r -a*b`$
* $`r 2*a*b`$
* $`r 3*a*b`$
* $`r 4*a*b`$

Meta-information
================
exname: My question
extype: schoice
exsolution: 10000
exshuffle: TRUE
````

The code to generate the several versions of the question:

```
library(exams)

setwd("/tmp/")

expargrid <- function(file, ...) {
  df <- expand.grid(...)
  stopifnot(nrow(df) >= 1L)
  sapply(1L:nrow(df), function(i) {
    args <- as.list(df[i,])
    args <- c(list(file = file), args)
    do.call(exams::expar, args)
  })
}

n <- 1

myquestions <- expargrid(paste0("question",sprintf("%02d", n),".Rmd"), a = 0:1, b = 0:1)

exams2moodle(myquestions,dir = "/tmp/", schoice=list(answernumbering="none"), name="PM")
```

Can the bad questions be eliminated automatically from the Moodle `xml` file generated by R/Exams?

Comment: One idea would be to check for items equality inside the `.Rmd` file and add a unique word to the bad questions via a R chunk. After that, one could go to the questions, with a R script, and look for the questions with the unique word -- the bad questions. However, I feel that this solution is not very elegant.

Comment: In the current development version of the package you get at least a warning that there are duplicated items in the question list. So you could catch that warning and act on it. However, I would recommend to assure unique solutions inside the R code of the .Rmd - rather than catching problems later outside of the .Rmd.

Comment: Thanks, Achim. I believe that I can accomplish my goal by using the parameter `envir` of your function `exams2moodle`, running it twice.

Comment: I think it's unlikely that this is the best way to cath such a behavior. If you are willing to run the function twice I can post a solution when I'm back at the computer.

Comment: You say my way is not the best one, and I must believe you, Achim. I am most curious to know what is the approach of your solution, for which I am in anticipation very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it is hard to catch such problems outside of the Rmd exercise files. Instead it would be better to write the R code in the exercise in such a way that it assures that the question list only contains unique items - and if that is not the case to keep on re-sampling the parameters until there is a version that works.

Part of the problem to catch the problem in general is also that it might depend on the random number generator and its seed because the problem might just occur very rarely.

In your special case, this is a bit different because you make a full grid of all possible combinations so that each exercise file does not have any random elements anymore. Here the best solution is to run an `exams2xyz()` interface (or the underlying `xexams()` function) once, inspect the output, eliminate the problematic exercise, and then run the desired `exams2xyz()` interface again.

Relying on your `myquestions` vector with four static variants of the dynamic `question01.Rmd` exercise template you could do:

```
myq_check <- xexams(myquestions)
## Warning messages:
## 1: In driver$read(file_tex[idj]) :
##   duplicated items in question list in '_tmp_Rtmpjhh2Lb_question01+60A32D0E+C9FE1'
## 2: In driver$read(file_tex[idj]) :
##   duplicated items in question list in '_tmp_Rtmpjhh2Lb_question01+60A32D0E+CA2C6'
## 3: In driver$read(file_tex[idj]) :
##   duplicated items in question list in '_tmp_Rtmpjhh2Lb_question01+60A32D0E+CA4CF'
```

This is similar to running `exams2moodle(myquestions)` but only weaves the Rmd files and reads them into R - without converting them to HTML and writing a Moodle XML file. Hence it's a bit faster and does not produce any files that would need to be cleaned up afterwards.

The output `myq_check` is a nested list with

- 1 list for `n = 1` random replication,
- each containing 4 lists pertaining to the four exercise files from `myquestions`,
- each containing 6 list elements with

  - `question` text,
  - `questionlist` with the question items,
  - `solution` text (if any, empty in this case),
  - `solutionlist` with the solution explanations (if any, empty here),
  - `metainfo` with the meta-information,
  - `supplements` with the file paths of supplementary files (if any, empty here).

Running `xexams(myquestions)` already warns about problems in three (ot of the four) exercise files. (You need to use R/exams version >= 2.4-0 to get these.) By inspecting the number of unique items in the `questionlist` we can find out which are affected by this:

```
ok <- sapply(myq_check[[1]], function(x) {
  length(x$questionlist) == length(unique(x$questionlist)) })
## exercise1 exercise2 exercise3 exercise4 
##     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE      TRUE
```

Thus, only the last exercise in `myquestions` is really suitable so you should subset before proceeding with `exams2moodle()`:

```
myquestions <- myquestions[ok]
exams2moodle(myquestions)
```

As already pointed out above. In this case this is sufficient to make the selection. If there is remaining randomness in the exercise files, this might not be enough to catch all problems. Then it would be better to program a custom solution into the Rmd exercise.

Comment: Brilliant, Achim! So much grateful to you!